# Setting DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled to true

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

The following code will let the workflow associated with the Incoming Email Enabled Library be started automatically when it is set to started when a new item is created.

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled= $true
$spWebService.Update()
```

My client is keen to know about any performance issues or limitations before setting it to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is with security, rather than performance.  [This KB article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140814123440/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/953289) describes the setting.

> This problem occurs because a security fix in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SP1 prevents declarative workflows from starting automatically under the system account. E-mail enabled list items are always created under the system account.

Also,

> To prevent the declarative workflows from impersonating the system account, the workflows will now impersonate the user who created the workflow association

So I guess this could possibly allow users to impersonate other users in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what hajamie outlines, I also had to go into Site Settings | Manage site features and enable Workflows can use app permissions, then do an iisreset to get a workflow to start automatically with an incoming email.  Just a note in case you decide to proceed with setting this to true.